# Sorting a double linked list full of 1000 elements containing random integers using insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I have written code to create the random list of 1000 integers between 0 and 1,000,000

```
Random randomGenerator =new Random();

    linkedList.insertAtStart(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000001));
    for (int i=1;i<999;++i)
    {
        linkedList.insertAtEnd(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000001));
    }
```

As well as functions for inserting at start, end, and at a position.

```
 public void insertAtStart(int val)
{
        Node nptr=new Node(d, null,null);
        if (head==null)
        {
            head=nptr;
            tail=head;
        }
        else

        {

            nptr.setPrev(tail);

            tail.setNext(nptr);

            tail = nptr;

        }

        size++;
    }
    public void insertAtEnd(int val)
{
        Node nptr=new Node(d, null,null);
        if (head==null)
        {
            head=nptr;
            tail=head;
        }
        else

        {

            nptr.setPrev(tail);

            tail.setNext(nptr);

            tail = nptr;

        }

        size++;
    }
    public void insert(int value,int index)
    {
    Node nptr = new Node(value,null,null);
            if (index==1)
            {
                insertAtStart(value);
                return;
            }
            Node ptr=head;


for(int i=2;i<=size;i++)
        {
            if(i==index)
            {
                Node tmp=ptr.getNext();
                ptr.setNext(nptr);
                nptr.setPrev(ptr);
                nptr.setNext(tmp);
                tmp.setPrev(nptr);
            }
        ptr=ptr.getNext();
        }
        size++;
}
```

these functions deal with the list size dynamically

My teacher would like us to write a function that will sort said random list of integers using an insertion sort. I am aware Collections.sort is an option but we are being asked to write our own. It should test the result by comparing each element of the sorted array to the one adjacent to it and reporting any out of order results. I understand how an insertion sort works for the most part but I am a bit fuzzy on the specifics on putting this into code. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my attempt at the insertion sort.. it sadly does not effect my DLL whatsoever

```
public void insertionSort(BetterArray linkedList)
    {
        Node ptr=head;
        for (int i = 1; i <linkedList.size; i++)
        {
            int currentElement=linkedList.get(i);
            int k;
            for(k=i-1;k>=0&&linkedList.get(i)>currentElement;k--)
            {   
                ptr.setNext(ptr.next);

        }
        ptr.setNext(ptr.next);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please _try_ putting it into code? If you understand how insertion sort works for the most part then I suggest you try writing something! If you're still having problems, come back to us with your attempt :)

Comment: [Here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm) is an insertion sort example in Java with an array, your Linked list sort should be the same.

Comment: Please do not add code as a comment, it's totally unreadable. Edit it and format it in your original post instead.

Comment: @tnw sorry new to this forum

Comment: @OlivierPoulin gave it a go, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in your implementation:

```
for(k = i-1; k >= 0 && linkedList.get(i) > currentElement; k--)
```

`linkedList.get(i)` should be `linkedList.get(k)`. Also, why are you using `setNext()`? Use your insert!

The first `ptr.setNext(ptr.next);` should be

```
linkedList.insert(linkedList.get(k), k+1);
linkedList.erase(k+2);
```

or, if you don't have erase, do you have `set()`?

And for the second `ptr.setNext(ptr.next);`, you should do the same as i previously described, except replace `k+1` with `currentElement`.